# Icon widget cut off by Image widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm trying to implement a "Change my profile picture" icon like how it appears in the profile page in Whatsapp, where a clickable camera icon hovers on the bottom right of the image.

This is the code I used inside a stateful widget:

```
Row(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Stack(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Container(
                        width: 120,
                        child: Image(
                          image: AssetImage('affogato.png'),
                        ),
                      ),
                      Positioned(
                        top: 70,
                        left: 90,
                        child: FloatingActionButton(
                          child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                          onPressed: () {},
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
```

Strangely, the Icon seems to take the constraints of the Image container. So when I set the width as 120 and try to push the Icon button to the bottom right edge of the Image, it gets cut off by the Image constraints. How do the constraints of the Container affect the FloatingActionButton even though they're siblings inside the Stack not parent-child widgets? And how can I fix this so that the Icon can float over the edge of the image?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I did it. I removed the `Positioned` widget completely and used `Padding` instead. It seemed to solve the problem. I also wrapped the image in a `CircleAvatar` to complete the Whatsapp style.

```
Row(
    children: <Widget>[
      Stack(
        children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0),
            child: CircleAvatar(
              radius: 70,
              backgroundColor: Colors.greenAccent,
              child: Container(
                height: 150,
                width: 150,
                child: ClipOval(
                  child: Image(
                    image: AssetImage('lib/rainy.png'),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 105, top: 80),
            child: Container(
              width: 50,
              height: 50,
              child: FloatingActionButton(
                backgroundColor: Colors.green,
                child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                onPressed: () async {},
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ],
  ),
```

Answer (score 1):

You can probably make use of `height` property of `Positioned` widget and adjust other dimensions (left, bottom, right, top) so that the button isn't cut-off at bottom right edge and is displayed properly. Working sample code below:

```
return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Row(
          children: <Widget>[
            Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                  Container(
                    width: 120,
                    child: Image(
                      image: AssetImage('assets/Icon-512.png'),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    bottom: 0,
                    right: 0,
                    left: 78,
                    height: 35,
                    child: FloatingActionButton(
                      child: Icon(Icons.camera_alt),
                      onPressed: () {},
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
          ],
        ),
      )

      // This trailing comma makes auto-formatting nicer for build methods.
    );
```

[image]

You might need to adjust dimensions per your need, but this way it doesn't cut-off the button.

Hope this answers your question.

Comment: Thanks! This does give a better output, although I find that if I push the `left` property of the Positioned widget a bit further to the edge of the image, the icon starts to get messed up.